# How to degrade gracefully when MEF component dependencies not installed?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, mef

I am developing an application which uses the MEF to plug-in interfaces to external equipment (I/O devices, oscilloscopes, waveform generators etc). Most of these interfaces need DLLs to access the equipment and, when possible, I pack these DLLs into the project containing the plug-ins.

The application uses `ImportMany` to load all classes which implement the plug-in interface. The user can then choose which interfaces are needed.

I have one interface which is causing me difficulties. I have not been able to identify all dependencies and when I start the application on another workstation I get an unresolved dependency error. I'm sure that when I install all the drivers and support DLLs then it would work ok.

However, not all users need to use this particular interface and I don't want to install all drivers on all workstations. I am looking for a way to degrade gracefully when some MEF plug-ins cannot be loaded. A log message would be enough to note that the interface could not be loaded. Only those trying to *use* the interface functions should get an error.

Here is my loader code:

```
try
{
    var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
    var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
    var batch = new CompositionBatch();
    batch.AddPart(this);
    catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof (Pruef.Net.TgtManager.TargetManager).Assembly));
    container.Compose(batch);

    _targets = _targets.OrderBy(t => t.DisplayName);
}
catch (Exception x)
{
    log.Error(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did to avoid the error. Thanks to @Gusdor for pointing me in the right direction. Lazy-loading seems to be the way to go.

```
public class TargetManager
{
    private static log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    [ImportMany(typeof(Pruef.Net.Contracts.ITarget))]
    private IEnumerable<Lazy<Pruef.Net.Contracts.ITarget>> _targets;

    public IEnumerable<Pruef.Net.Contracts.ITarget> AvailableTargets
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load all known target definitions
    /// </summary>
    public void Init()
    {
        try
        {
            var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
            var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
            var batch = new CompositionBatch();
            batch.AddPart(this);
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Pruef.Net.TgtManager.TargetManager).Assembly));
            container.Compose(batch);

            List<ITarget> result = new List<ITarget>();
            foreach (Lazy<ITarget> t in _targets)
            {
                try
                {
                    result.Add(t.Value);
                }
                catch (Exception x)
                {
                    // could not load plugin
                    // log error and continue
                    log.Error(x);
                }
            }
            result = result.OrderBy(t => t.DisplayName).ToList();
            AvailableTargets = result;
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            log.Error(x);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `AllowDefault` property of the Import attribute.

```
[Import(AllowDefault=true)]
```

From the docs:

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the property, field, or
>   parameter will be set to its type's default value when an export with
>   the contract name is not present in the container.

*NOTE: If you plugin throws and exception on creation, you application will still fail. Exceptions resulting in missing drivers should still be handled.*

Comment: +1 thanks for the tip. Actually, I'm using `ImportMany` but I see that there is a lazy-loading option (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee155691(v=vs.110).aspx#types_of_imports). I'll check that out now. [Greetings from the Black Forest to my home town- Soton :-) ]

Comment: @paul lazy initialization is a good shout. It will allow you to trap creation exceptions quite nicely!

Comment: Re NOTE. I guess that is happening. The class loading will always fail because of the missing dependencies :-(